# Persistent EACCES (Permision Denied) error when opening video since upgrading to KitKat

Tags: android, permissions, android-videoview, filenotfoundexception, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using a VideoView and all I want to do is hardcode a file path into `videoView.setVideoPath(...)`.

The following code worked perfectly fine until I upgraded my device to KitKat:

```
videoView.setVideoPath(
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myVideo.mp4");
```

But now I get a FileNotFoundException: "open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)". Any ideas on how to get this working?

**Note: I figured this out. My manifest didn't have** 
`<uses-permission>android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`